# Android - not able to attach a file in email

Tags: android, email, attachment

By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).

I am able to see the file "/data/data/package_name/files/ in file explore in DDMS, but when i attached the above file URI using imageUri in email , then i saw that attached file is of 0kb.
i have used the default email APIs of Android.

Can anyone suggest me ,how to attach a file in email that is private to the application?

although i am successful able to save the file in SD card and attaching the file from SD card , this is working fine.

But if SD card is not available and saving the file to the internal storage , then how can i attach them in email.

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file.txt";
String string = "hello world!";FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();

File imageFile = getFileStreamPath(FILENAME );
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("*/*");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);

this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."),SUB_ACTIVITY);
```

Comment: I faced the similar issue. From SD card that works just fine... But from internal storage I didn't succeed in this functionality. Maybe playing with MIME types will help to go on..

Comment: could you please elobrate it ?

Comment: Personally I  used the following code to send attached .html file: Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setType("text/html");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "scor card");
 File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File(sdDir, Preferences.PATH_TO_SAVE_ON_SD_CARD + "/scoreHtml.html");
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));

Comment: but in the above code, SD card is being used. i want to attach the image in email without storing it into SD card.

Comment: Did you ever ran across a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

When you try to attach file from internal storage, GMail writes an error to the log:

```
ERROR/Gmail(...): file:// attachment paths must point to file:///mnt/sdcard.
```

E-mail application would show you the attached file even if it didn't physically exist.

As for an external storage, documentation says that:

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage.

That means you don't have to worry about device not having an external storage at all. Still, external storage can be unavailable at times. Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out why it was failing and I didn't think to change the filters on my LogCat window.

Answer (score 5):

```
Android: Attaching files from internal cache to Gmail




package com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach; 

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 

import android.content.ContentProvider; 
import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.UriMatcher; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor; 
import android.util.Log; 

public class CachedFileProvider extends ContentProvider { 

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "CachedFileProvider"; 

    // The authority is the symbolic name for the provider class 
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach.provider"; 

    // UriMatcher used to match against incoming requests 
    private UriMatcher uriMatcher; 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() { 
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH); 

        // Add a URI to the matcher which will match against the form 
        // 'content://com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach.provider/*' 
        // and return 1 in the case that the incoming Uri matches this pattern 
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*", 1); 

        return true; 
    } 

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) 
            throws FileNotFoundException { 

        String LOG_TAG = CLASS_NAME + " - openFile"; 

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, 
                "Called with uri: '" + uri + "'." + uri.getLastPathSegment()); 

        // Check incoming Uri against the matcher 
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) { 

        // If it returns 1 - then it matches the Uri defined in onCreate 
        case 1: 

            // The desired file name is specified by the last segment of the 
            // path 
            // E.g. 
            // 'content://com.stephendnicholas.gmailattach.provider/Test.txt' 
            // Take this and build the path to the file 
            String fileLocation = getContext().getCacheDir() + File.separator 
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment(); 

            // Create & return a ParcelFileDescriptor pointing to the file 
            // Note: I don't care what mode they ask for - they're only getting 
            // read only 
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File( 
                    fileLocation), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY); 
            return pfd; 

            // Otherwise unrecognised Uri 
        default: 
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Unsupported uri: '" + uri + "'."); 
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unsupported uri: "
                    + uri.toString()); 
        } 
    } 

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Not supported / used / required for this example 
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, 
            String[] as) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) { 
        return null; 
    } 

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) { 
        return null; 
    } 

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String s, String[] as1, 
            String s1) { 
        return null; 
    } 
}




<provider android:name="CachedFileProvider" android:authorities="com.stephendnicholas





public static void createCachedFile(Context context, String fileName, 
            String content) throws IOException { 

    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator 
                + fileName); 
    cacheFile.createNewFile(); 

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile); 
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8"); 
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw); 

    pw.println(content); 

    pw.flush(); 
    pw.close(); 
}




public static Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email, 
            String subject, String body, String fileName) { 

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent( 
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

    //Explicitly only use Gmail to send 
    emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"); 

    emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 

    //Add the recipients 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                new String[] { email }); 

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body); 

    //Add the attachment by specifying a reference to our custom ContentProvider 
    //and the specific file of interest 
    emailIntent.putExtra( 
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
                Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/"
                        + fileName)); 

    return emailIntent; 
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, but adding the source would be nice  : http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974 . I also found it useful as its a bit more structured.

Answer (score 4):

In order to share a private file you need to use a ContentProvider to provide access to your file by other applications. Here's a great example: [Android: Attaching files from internal cache to Gmail](http://stephendnicholas.com/posts/android-attaching-files-from-internal-cache-to-gmail).

Also, although the tutorial mentions that you need to declare your provider in the Android manifest file, it does not specify that it should be contained in `<application>`, so make sure that when you declare it is within `<application> </application>`.

Answer (score 3):

This Code may help you out to get idea about attachment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
    textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String to = textTo.getText().toString();
            String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("plain/text");
            File data = null;

            try {
                Date dateVal = new Date();
                String filename = dateVal.toString();
                data = File.createTempFile("Report", ".csv");
                FileWriter out = (FileWriter) GenerateCsv.generateCsvFile(
                                                data, "Name,Data1");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(data));
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "E-mail"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class GenerateCsv
{
    public static FileWriter generateCsvFile(File sFileName,String fileContent) 
    {
        FileWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
            writer.append(fileContent);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return writer;
    }
}
```

The above code requires you add the following permission to your manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) instead of Context.MODE_PRIVATE when saving the file. Then other apps will have access to the file.

Comment: @ , i had already tried with MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this problem using internal files and although I have used openFileInput with MODE_WORLD_READABLE on /data/data//files/testFileName.txt and used the URI.parse with the extra "/" (see below), the received test emailed is still lacking the desired attachment. So sorry but there is no answer, except try to use External files on the SD Card - which is my next experiment!

> > Code :

```
File tmpFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), mfileName);
        Log.d(TAG, tmpFile.toString());  
// This shows: /data/data/org.eddiem.adeveloper.flatfiletest/files/testFile.csv 
        //File tmpFile2 = new File(context.getFileStreamPath(mfileName), mfileName);
        //Log.v(TAG, tmpFile2.toString());
// This also shows: /data/data/org.eddiem.adeveloper.flatfiletest/files/testFile.csv 

        //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getFileStreamPath(mfileName), mfileName));
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + tmpFile.toString()); 
        //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
        //                              mfileName));
        Log.d(TAG, "Uri-path is: " + uri.getPath()); // or .toString()

        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"eddie.moxey@sky.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Email - with Attachment");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a test Email with an Attachment.");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and following worked for me.

First send Broadcast to notify device that file is created / mounted.

For example:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+storagePath)));
```

Then use code to send mail with attachment.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  "Receiver Email Address" );
email.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Email Text");

//Mime type of the attachment (or) u can use sendIntent.setType("*/*")
//email.setType("text/plain");
email.setType("application/YourMimeType");

//Full Path to the attachment
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+storagePath));
try
{
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Message..."));
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{

}
```